# Select option is not getting cleared once set to 0 in javscript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reset the select `option` while another option is selected to `0`. So I tried below code.

```js
    if (varALPO1MobNum == "0") {                    
                    var selectElement = $('#ddlALPO1STUpd');
                    resetSelectElement(selectElement); // here I want to reset it to 0
                    $('#ddlALPO1STUpd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $('#ddlALPO1STUpd').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
```

And the source code HTML for the same is below

```html
    <select name="ctl00$ddlALPO1STUpd" id="ddlALPO1STUpd" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
         <option value="0">--Select--</option>
         <option value="Base">Base</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Primary">Primary</option>
       <option value="Additional">Additional</option></select>
```

The above logic is not working and resetting to `0`. Please suggest what is wrong here

Also reset code is below

```
function resetSelectElement(selectElement) {
selectElement.selectedIndex = 0;
```

}

Comment: @Pointy:  added that code for reference

Comment: You are passing a jQuery object into that reset function, but the function expects a DOM element reference.

Comment: So what should I pass their ?

Comment: Either change the function to `selectElement.prop("selectedIndex", 0)` or else pass `$('#ddlALPO1STUpd')[0]`.

Comment: I recommend you use the $prefix on jQuery objects: `let $selectElement = $('#ddlALPO1STUpd'); resetSelectElement($selectElement);` using `const resetSelectElement = $selectElement => $selectElement[0].selectedIndex = 0;` or remove the function and just have `$('#ddlALPO1STUpd').val(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the $prefix on jQuery objects:

```
let $selectElement = $('#ddlALPO1STUpd'); 
resetSelectElement($selectElement);
```

using

```
const resetSelectElement = $selectElement => $selectElement[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

or remove the function and just have

```
$('#ddlALPO1STUpd').val(0);
```

Like this - not I changed to prop and pass the boolean

```js
const $selectElement = $('#ddlALPO1STUpd');
$selectElement.prop('disabled', varALPO1MobNum === "0"); 
if (varALPO1MobNum === "0") $selectElement.val(0);
```